# MySql Selecting average rating per date between two dates

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has (among other things) a rating between 0 and 4 and the date it was sent.

I'd like to know it's possible to select the average rating we get on a date for every date between two dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it uses all the obvious SQL operators:

```
select date, avg(rating) avg_rating
from table
where date between :start and :end
group by date
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm pretty new to Mysql, didn't know about the "group by" operator

Answer (score 1):

Sure, this is pretty basic SQL.

```
SELECT AVG(rating) AS rating, rating_date FROM ratings GROUP BY rating_date;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm pretty new to Mysql, didn't know about the "group by" operator
I think the other guy answered a couple of seconds before you so I'll have to give him the correct answer, sorry